# How to Center a row-column grid in a <div>. HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple web-app that displays an icon grid. I'm getting the grid part to display and size appropriately, but I want it to be centered in the div class that contains it.

The examples I saw for centering content all involved `margin: 0 auto;` but I can't seem to do that AND have the `float: left` required for the row-column set up to display correctly; the `float: left` appears to override any margin I set.

Is there any solution to this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="blobRegion">    
    <div class="b2_center_view">
        <div class="rows";>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>@item.desc</h3>
                    <p>@item.chassis</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Here's the style code for `column` `center_view` and `blobRegion`

```
.column {
    float: left;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 180px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 4px solid #001a00;
    background-color: #fffbf4;
}

.center_view {
    grid-column: 2 / 8;
    font-size: larger;
}

.blobRegion {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
    .blobRegion > div {
        border: 4px solid #001a00;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #fffbf4;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #4d0000;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;     
    }
```

And here's what it looks like -

1) with the window being resized, expanded horizontally:

[image]

2) with the window expanded a little bit further (making enough room for another column):

[image]

Basically I want that white space that grows on the right side until there's enough space for another column when the window is expanded, to grow equally on either side of the icon grid. So the columns will "float" in the middle of the parent `<div>` `b2_center_view` if that makes sense.

I know how to center static data or images in nested divs, but I can't get it to work with this row-column setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your columns to fill available place, but to remain centered, here is nice trick without using float or grid, just inline block. It is simpler and practical:

```css
.rows {
  /* set text-align: center; to parent */
  text-align: center;
  
  /* your custom styling */
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.column {
  /*give column display: inline-block; and set parent (rows) to text-align: center;*/
  display: inline-block;
  
  /*your custom styling*/
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 180px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blobRegion">    
    <div class="b2_center_view">
        <div class="rows";>
        
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>Some Headline</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph goes here bla bla</p>
                </div>
                
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

See snippet in full page and resize browser.